# How to add values to an existing empty value key dictionary from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary, key-value

I have the following code to create empty dictionary:

```
empty_dict = dict.fromkeys(['apple','ball'])
empty_dict = {'apple': None, 'ball': None}
```

I have this empty dictionary.

Now I want to add the values from value.txt which has the following content:

```
value.txt
1
2
```

I want the resultant dictionary to be as:

```
{
"apple" : 1,
"ball" : 2
}
```

I'm not sure how to update only the value from the dictionary.

Comment: Do you want to assign values (1, 2) in the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to make the dict first — it makes it inconvenient to get the order correct. You can just [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the keys and the file lines and pass it to the dictionary constructor like:

```
keys = ['apple','ball']

with open(path, 'r') as file:
    d = dict(zip(keys, map(str.strip, file)))

print(d)
# {'apple': '1', 'ball': '2'}
```

This uses [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) to remove the `\n` characters from the lines in the file.

It's not clear what should happen if you have more lines than keys, but the above will ignore them.